# mongodb is it possible to install on 3 server 3 shards each of which has replica set

Tags: mongodb, server, sharding, replicaset

I'm designing mongodb shard with replica on 3 servers.
Because of cost, currently I can buy only 3 servers.

So, what I will do is like this:

```
server 1:
    mongos
    mongod config
    mongod primary shard1
    mongod secondary shard2
    mongod secondary shard3


server 2:
    mongos
    mongod config
    mongod primary shard2
    mongod secondary shard1
    mongod secondary shard3


server 3:
    mongos
    mongod config
    mongod primary shard3
    mongod secondary shard1
    mongod secondary shard2


Load balancer
    mongos on server1
    mongos on server2
    mongos on server3
```

Is this kind of setting possible?

I want to get confirmation before buying new servers.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

self answer.

After reading mongodb document, I got confidence that above configuration can be set. I will post result here after try.